# How to compare Coronavirus deaths between countries

Tags: resolution, coronavirus

Leaving aside the problem of how deaths are counted (in some countries a doctor diagnoses the case, others insist on a positive test, some only count hospital deaths), how do we accurately compare between countries?

Raw numbers of deaths cannot be used because some countries have larger populations than others. Deaths per 100,000 population is a little better but in the UK, the majority of the deaths are in the large cities of London and Birmingham. These large death figures concentrated into two cities are diluted by the uninfected population elsewhere. This website https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/52311014 suggests comparing like with like e.g. London with New York, both being globalized cities, but how do you define "like"?

My idea is to calculate number of deaths per 100,000 in each region in the country (e.g. Public Health Area, Superoutput area - as small a region as data can be obtained for). Then create a raster of death/100k per grid square in each region. International comparisons could then be made by ranking countries by number of grid squares in each category. That is those with large numbers of high value death/100k squares would be considered most impacted by the virus. Deaths would be thus compared to the immediately surrounding population rather than the population of the entire country.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: I'd rather go for "deaths per pop per region" and then divide this ratio by "pop per sqkm", so in the end you'd take into account population density.

Comment: Reasonbleness is very much a subjective topic, which makes it difficult to answer in a Focused question/Best answer framework.